# Using xlwings in a loop: You must first instantiate a Workbook object

Tags: python, xlwings

I have the following iteration:

```
for key, df in dictHistory.items():

    wb = Workbook(file_path)
    Range(key, "A1").value = df
    wb.save()
    wb.close()
```

Where `dictHistory` is of type `<String,pd.DataFrame>`, so to speak.

The file exists, and the sheet exists in the file.

Yet when running I am getting the following error:

```
NameError: You must first instantiate a Workbook object.
```

And

```
xlwings.__version__
```

yields:

```
'0.3.2'
```

Comment: Any chance you can upgrade to the latest version of xlwings? we've come a long way since 0.3.2

Comment: I can't replicate the issue, even with 0.3.2, using the following test dictHistory: `dictHistory = {1: 10, 2: 20, 3:30}`